# handle subscription changes in android in-app billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, subscription

Say my user has a 4 month subscription. One month within it, she wants to move to a yearly subscription. How does google play in-app billing handle this? Is there a method to move user from one subscription into another? I am considering the real effects of possibly billing errors such as overcharging a user, etc. The idea of charging the user only 1/4th of the 4-month subscription and then canceling it and then starting the yearly version. Does in-app billing handle these issues?

Comment: you got solution for this one.

Comment: @Sakthi can you guys please share your solution here. I am having same thought in mind. Don't have idea how to handle it.